# Using RxJS subscribe operator in Angular 2 observable

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

Here is my service TypeScript file.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Request, RequestOptions, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CarService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    Url: string = 'url/of/api';
    getCar(){
        var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('API-Key-For-Authentification', 'my_own_key_goes_here');
            headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers })
        return this.http.get(this.Url, options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    }
}
```

Above gets injected to the component bellow.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CarService} from 'path/to/car.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    providers: [ CarService ],
    template: `
        <div>
            <button (click)="getCar()">Get Car</button>
            <h2>The car has {{ tiresCount }} tires.</h2>
        </div>
    `
})
export class Home {
    tiresCount: number;
    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }
    getCar() {
        this.carService.getCar()
            .subscribe(function(data){
                this.tiresCount = data.tires.count;
                console.log(this.tiresCount); // 4
        };
        console.log(this.tiresCount); // undefined
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is to display the number of tires in the view of the Home component when the button is clicked. The problem is that, when I `console.log(this.tiresCount)` inside the `.subscribe` parentheses, it logs `4` but logs `undefined` outside of it. This means that the local property `tiresCount` did not get the new value so that it won't display anything in the view.

I suspect I am missing something obvious. Or perhaps, the understanding of Observables and/or RxJS is needed here as I am new to them.

Comment: Observables in this case function in a nearly identical manner to promises...asynchronous by nature.  As a result, you're expecting that your outside console.log will be defined when it runs, but it won't.  It'll fire off the call to getCar and THEN hit the outside console.log BEFORE the async response is returned.

Comment: That makes sense, but I am also trying to understand why the local property `tiresCount` does not receive the new value after the response is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [lambda expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) "aka, arrow function" instead of `function(){..}` in your subscribe method. When using `function(){...}`, `this` inside it will refer to the function itself instead of the `Home` component class.

```
getCar() {
    this.carService.getCar()
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.tiresCount = data.tires.count;
                console.log(this.tiresCount); // 4
    });
    console.log(this.tiresCount); // undefined
}
someWhereElse(){
    console.log(this.tiresCount); // 4 , only after getCar().subscribe() resolves 
}
```

Comment: This worked. What `this` refers to was crucial. Also, I did not know the syntax of the lambda expression requires { } around the statements. I tried without them first and it did not work, so I used `function(){..}` instead, which was not a good idea. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome @jayscript, the lambda expression does **not** require `{...}` unless the body is multiline. Otherwise you can just `.subscribe(data=>this.tiresCount=data.tires.count)`